# Read a Tab-Delimited file and output formatted rows

Tags: perl

New to Perl: I have a 500-row tab-delimited text file that looks like this:

```
-24.30869102    -69.83711243    55.14122391 2018-09-23T05:32:11.909
```

I want to output a 500-row text file where each line looks like this:

```
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime('2018-09-23T05:32:11.909')}
```

The following code, though, doesn't produce that line.  It produces this:

```
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime(2018-09-23T05:32:11.909
-21.58013344)}
```

I can't get the datetime in the UTCDateTime to have apostrophes, and another latitude (next row) is added at the ended.  Why?  My code is provided below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $input, "<", "all_data.txt")
    or die "Can't open < file: $!";

my $output = 'formatted_hypo.txt';
open my $outfh, '>', $output;

while (my $line = <$input>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @columns = split /\t/, $line;
    my $lat = $columns[0];
    my $lon = $columns[1];
    my $dep = $columns[2];
    my $time = $columns[3];

    printf $outfh ("{'lat': %.2f, 'lon': %.2f, 'dep': %2d, 'time': UTCDateTime(%s)}", $lat,$lon,$dep,$time);
}
```

Comment: NOTE: Is it CSV (comma separated value) or TSV (tab separated value) file? In header you stated CVS but in the message TSV data file.

Comment: Apologies - it's tab-delimited, and I made the change above.

Comment: Looks like the `<$input>` somehow returns two lines together (so then `split`ing on tabs leaves the timestamp and the next thing, `-21.58`, as one field).  It's about your data, the shown code seems correct.  I don't know how and why this would happen ... faulty linefeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, your code looks to me as correct -- for some reason it looks like `chomp` did not strip `\n` from the line.

I slightly changed your code and it produces expected result 
(I read data from **DATA** block with output to the screen)

```
use strict;
use warnings;


while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;

    my($lat,$lon,$dep,$time) = split /\t/, $line;

    printf "{'lat': %.2f, 'lon': %.2f, 'dep': %2d, 'time': UTCDateTime('%s')}\n", 
                $lat+0,
                $lon+0,
                $dep+0,
                $time;
}

__DATA__
-24.30869102    -69.83711243    55.14122391 2018-09-23T05:32:11.909
-24.30869103    -69.83711242    55.14122392 2018-09-23T05:32:11.910
-24.30869104    -69.83711241    55.14122392 2018-09-23T05:32:11.911
-24.30869105    -69.83711240    55.14122392 2018-09-23T05:32:11.912
```

output

```
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime('2018-09-23T05:32:11.909')}
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime('2018-09-23T05:32:11.910')}
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime('2018-09-23T05:32:11.911')}
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime('2018-09-23T05:32:11.912')}
```

NOTE: in future please provide 3-5 lines of data from a file you process

Comment: But that's the output the OP doesn't want. What he wants is `'...'` around the timestamp.

Comment: I do not see any reference to `...` in his post. He refers to apostrophes -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe

Comment: Yes, `...` just means "some stuff" - so he wants apostrophes around the timestamp. I see you've changed your code to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I think that all you need to do here is to put single quote marks around the `%s` in your `printf()` statement.

```
printf $outfh ("{'lat': %.2f, 'lon': %.2f, 'dep': %2d, 'time': UTCDateTime('%s')}", $lat, $lon, $dep, $time);
```

I then get this output:

```
{'lat': -24.31, 'lon': -69.84, 'dep': 55, 'time': UTCDateTime('2018-09-23T05:32:11.909')}
```